# Error send message

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send an email

```
html = get_html_mail(self.request, order)

email = EmailMultiAlternatives('Subject',
                         html,
                         'no-reply@natarelochke.ru',
                         # to=[order.shop.email])
                         to=['......@gmail.com'])
email.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
email.send()
```

But have error, when i try send email:

```
AttributeError at /success/

'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

How i can fix it?

```
def get_html_mail(req, order):
    request = req

    return render(request, 'send_mail/send_message.html', {'order': order})
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Форма заказа</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="padd" style="width:15px;" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="padd" style="width:15px;" ></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="padd" style="width:15px;" ></td>
```

That is html for my message. it is render and should send on mail address

Comment: Can you show the line with the actual error, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `splitlines` somewhere on a `HttpResponse`. The `HttpResponse` has no method `splitlines`. The error is not produced by the code snippet you added to your question.

[Source of the django's HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/http/response/#HttpResponse)

Find where you are attempting to let your `HttpResponse` use the `splitlines` method. Start with removing the **not existing** `splitlines` on your `HttpResponse`.

Comment: i add new data in my question please see that

Comment: Share your code `success` method. This newly added code also does contain the issue. After the submit or send, you're being redirected to the  `success` method, or this method is being called. I'ts the method bound to the `/success/` url, notified by the error. That method contains the `HttpResponse` with the error.

Answer (score 1):

just set `render` to `render_to_string` ty all for the time